# login to programme java using hsqldb?

Tags: java, hsqldb

hi i need help in my programme i need to vérifier login from my database hsqldb to access to my programme in mysql everything is good bat in hsqldb is not wanting to work at all
i using hsqldb is memory database this is my code i using

for connection to database:

```
Connection conn = null;

private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String PASSWD = "toor";
private static final String CONN_STRING ="jdbc:hsqldb:Data/explorecalifornia";

 public static Connection Conne_HSQLDB(){


        try {
           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING,USERNAME,PASSWD);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            return conn;

           }catch(SQLException e){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage()+ "\nCode: " + e.getErrorCode());
               return null;
        }
    }
```

for login this is my code

```
 if(UserTFD.getText().length()==0 || PassTFD.getText().length()==0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "un champ est vider !");
            }else{


                String sql = "select * from LOGIN WHERE USERNAME=? and PASSWORD=?";
            try(
                    Connection conn=ConxDB.Conne_HSQLDB();
                    PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);


                    ){
                      pst.setString(1, UserTFD.getText());
                      pst.setString(2, PassTFD.getText());
                      ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                 if(rs.next()){
                         dispose();
                         new SettingGUI().setVisible(true);
                     }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }


            }
```

and the message erreur is

```
user lacks privilege or object not found: LOGIN
```

for my database this is my the code

```
SET DATABASE UNIQUE NAME HSQLDB397995F7ED
SET DATABASE GC 0
SET DATABASE DEFAULT RESULT MEMORY ROWS 0
SET DATABASE EVENT LOG LEVEL 0
SET DATABASE SQL NAMES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL REGULAR NAMES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL REFERENCES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL SIZE FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TYPES FALSE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC DELETE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TDC UPDATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL TRANSLATE TTI TYPES TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONCAT NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL NULLS FIRST TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL UNIQUE NULLS TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL CONVERT TRUNCATE TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL AVG SCALE 0
SET DATABASE SQL DOUBLE NAN TRUE
SET DATABASE SQL LONGVAR IS LOB FALSE
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS
SET DATABASE DEFAULT ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
SET DATABASE TRANSACTION ROLLBACK ON CONFLICT TRUE
SET DATABASE TEXT TABLE DEFAULTS ''
SET FILES WRITE DELAY 20
SET FILES BACKUP INCREMENT FALSE
SET FILES CACHE SIZE 10000
SET FILES CACHE ROWS 50000
SET FILES SCALE 1
SET FILES LOB SCALE 32
SET FILES DEFRAG 0
SET FILES NIO TRUE
SET FILES NIO SIZE 256
SET FILES LOG TRUE
SET FILES LOG SIZE 200
CREATE USER SA PASSWORD DIGEST 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
CREATE USER "root" PASSWORD DIGEST '7b24afc8bc80e548d66c4e7ff72171c5'
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION DBA
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.LOGIN(ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,USERNAME VARCHAR(40),PASSWORD VARCHAR(40))
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.LOGIN ALTER COLUMN ID RESTART WITH 3
ALTER SEQUENCE SYSTEM_LOBS.LOB_ID RESTART WITH 1
SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.YES_OR_NO TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TIME_STAMP TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CARDINAL_NUMBER TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_DATA TO PUBLIC
GRANT USAGE ON DOMAIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SQL_IDENTIFIER TO PUBLIC
GRANT DBA TO SA
GRANT DBA TO "root"
SET SCHEMA PUBLIC
INSERT INTO LOGIN VALUES(1,'root','toor')
INSERT INTO LOGIN VALUES(2,'onee','onee')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an HSQLDB Server for your database and connect to this server for queries.

The usual problems for a setup like yours are:

1. Each Java process interpretes the relative file: database path according to the directory where the process was started. This may create an empty database. You can avoid this by adding `;ifexists=true` to the end of the connection URL. See this http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_connection_props
2. Simultaneous direct access to a file: database from multiple java processes is not possible.

Running a Server allows you to connect reliably from different processes.

Answer (score 0):

`d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` its the encoded value of an empty password.

Try these credentials:

```java
private static final String USERNAME = "sa";
private static final String PASSWD = "";
```